# Making the text Bold using ( '\033[1m' + String ) doesn't work with python 2.7 in my mac

Tags: python-2.7

When I run the code `print '\033[1m' + 'string'` in both python 2.7 as well as in python 3.4, it prints this `[1mstring`. I don't understand what the problem is. Please help me here.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

That escape sequence will be interpreted via your tty (terminal) session, *not* the python IDLE shell.  You will find this is the case for many escape sequences.

[image]

vs

[image]

Answer (score -1):

the problem is you have a
Macbook

try either updating the python version or use a windows emulator

Comment: A general overarching assumption such as a person's operating system may not actually assist a person. Providing additional support information and evidence with your answer will be of help. Your answer comes across as low effort, really consider adding more.